# Signals are received twice in OMNet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have created my own OMNet++ Listener class as follows:

**headerfile**

```
#ifndef MYFRAMELISTENER_H_
#define MYFRAMELISTENER_H_



#include <clistener.h>
#include <vector>

class MyFrameListener : public cListener{
public:
    int tempDelmeJustForTest;
    simsignal_t signalIDArray[14];
    int index;
public:
    MyFrameListener();
    virtual ~MyFrameListener();

    virtual void receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, cObject *obj);
};

#endif /* MYFRAMELISTENER_H_ */
```

**cc File**

```
MyFrameListener::MyFrameListener() {
    this->tempDelmeJustForTest = 0;
}

MyFrameListener::~MyFrameListener() {
}

void MyFrameListener::receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, cObject *obj){
        tempDelmeJustForTest++;
}
```

**SimpleModule cc file**:

```
void ListenersModule::initialize()
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
    frameListener = new MyFrameListener();
    //subscribe("packetReceivedFromLower",frameListener);
    simulation.getSystemModule()->subscribe("packetReceivedFromLower",frameListener);
}


void ListenersModule::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
}


void ListenersModule::finish(){
    //simulation.getSystemModule()->unsubscribe("packetReceivedFromLower",frameListener);
    recordScalar("My Listened Values", this->frameListener->tempDelmeJustForTest);
}
```

Here, I am trying to count the number of Ethernet frames received in `EtherMACFullDuplex` by incrementing the `tempDelmeJustForTest` variable.

`EtherMACFullDuplex` is a module located in `inet/src/inet/linklayer/ethernet/EtherMACFullDuplex.cc` and it is used to create the `Ethernet phy` port.

This class has a function as shown below:

```
void EtherMACFullDuplex::processReceivedDataFrame(EtherFrame *frame)
{
    emit(packetReceivedFromLowerSignal, frame);

    // strip physical layer overhead (preamble, SFD) from frame
    frame->setByteLength(frame->getFrameByteLength());

    // statistics
    unsigned long curBytes = frame->getByteLength();
    numFramesReceivedOK++;
    numBytesReceivedOK += curBytes;
    emit(rxPkOkSignal, frame);

    numFramesPassedToHL++;
    emit(packetSentToUpperSignal, frame);
    // pass up to upper layer
    EV_INFO << "Sending " << frame << " to upper layer.\n";
    send(frame, "upperLayerOut");
}
```

It emits a signal  "packetReceivedFromLower" and my listner has subscribed to it as shown in the above code.

Problem is the counter shows **tempDelmeJustForTest = 12** when the sender sends only **6 Ethernet Frames**. Why ?

[image]

Also, I am project referencing `Core4Inet` project other than the `Inet` project.

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as described on http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: Updated the question detail. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: From the code you pasted I cannot see how many hosts exist in your network. I am guessing three?

Comment: yes, its Three. All are Core4Inet's Ethernethosts. But i am sending to only ieee8021QEtherHost not to ieee8021QEtherHost1. I have confirmed this in GUI and in cole too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are overhearing the signal emitted by the MAC layer of the destination host and the MAC layer of the switch.

By subscribing not just at your own module, but at the module returned by `simulation.getSystemModule()`, you are overhearing all signals of type *packetReceivedFromLower* emitted anywhere in the simulation. The ["Subscribing to Signals" chapter of the user manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec:simple-modules:signals-api) has more information on this mechanism.

If you want to know where the signal you are overhearing was emitted from, you can use the `source` parameter of your `receiveSignal` method.

Answer (score 1):

The counter `tempDelmeJustForTest` shows 12 when the sender sends 6 Ethernet Frames, because the method `processReceivedDataFrame` is involved 6 times in your switch and 6 times in destination host.
The command:

```
simulation.getSystemModule()->subscribe("packetReceivedFromLower",frameListener);
```

means that the listener will receive the signal from *any* element (i.e. including switch). 
You can check which module sent a signal by adding one line in `receiveSignal()`:

```
void MyFrameListener::receiveSignal(cComponent *source, simsignal_t signalID, cObject *obj){
  EV << "Signal from " << source->getFullPath() << endl;     
  tempDelmeJustForTest++;
}
```

Comment: Where is the "simulation" object from?

Comment: Actually, macro `simulation` has been removed 4 years ago. It was replaced by `getSimulation()`. Take a look at [ChangeLog](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/src/sim/ChangeLog).